# Wifi Direct to configure new device (a la chromecast setup)

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I've been digging around the developer docs for Android, and a fair bit elsewhere, yet I've been unable to find the information needed. In short, I'd like to replicate the "adding a new device to a known network" experience in a proprietary app on Android. So assuming a new device is discoverable directly with Wifi Direct, how can you then add this new device to the classic AP network the Android handheld is registered to?

For further example/reference, the Google Home app makes this process relatively foolproof. It discovers a wireless Chromecast device via Wifi Direct, then seamlessly adds it to its known network with appropriate credentials.

If anyone is able to direct me to some reference material that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Continued reading of various articles seems to imply that to pull credentials one needs to have root/admin access. This can happen at the OEM level, but user apps aren't "ever" given this sort of permission short of jailbreaking. My guess is that with such permissions the process involves scraping `wpa_supplicant.conf`